# PHP extending requires on files

Tags: php, parent-child, parent, require

I have a problem where I would like assistence with.

Currently on working on a new project for myself and I am trying to start with a good foundation.

I have build the following file structure (relavant part):

- Class/
- Class/class.filename.php
- Class/class.etc.php
- Func/
- Func/func.filename.php
- Func/func.etc.php
- Config/config.php
- index.php

In my config file all classes and functions are included with the require_once function (I loop alle files and directories inside func and class). In the folder class the file for firePHP is located which I include and then setup in the config.php.

In my config.php and index.php I can call this log function perfectly, but when I use it in one of the func.filename.php or class.filename.php it errors. The child (func/class) is not seeing the other included functions within config.php.

Hope somebody can help me out with this.

Comment: You should be using an **autoloader**, only including the necessary files whenever they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You func.filename.php file needs to "require_once" the file that contains the log function.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that may work for you (since you have this structure) is to have all your required files in `config.php` (included with `require_once(<file>)`). This seems to work. Then, when other files required any other function for other files, just `require_once('config.php')`.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to only include what you need, when you need it. Why spend the time loading 50 different classes/functions/snippets when you might only need 2 or 3 for the script at hand? Paring out unnecessary include statements can increase the performance of your scripts *considerably*.

1. Make use of the [`__autoload()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function for classes. It is just super.
2. Chain `include_once()` or `require_once()` through your various files so that grabbing one file that you need for a given job automatically gets its own dependencies.